# How can I cancel the trigger of a function by clicking on an element?

Tags: jquery

I created a slider that automatically triggers at a certain time. I set that when I click on an element behind the slider, it will come in front and have data-position = 1. The problem is that when I click on the element that is already in front, it starts my function and tries to add it in front, even if it already is, and this effect happens: https://vimeo.com/378484003 . How can I cancel the click for the item that is already in front?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

// get active
var get_active = $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").data("class");
$("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
$("#dp-dots li[data-class=" + get_active + "]").addClass("active");


var num = 1;

$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function () {
    var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
    num = get_slide;
    generalClick(get_slide);
});

function generalClick(number) {
    $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
    $("#dp-dots li:nth-child(" + number + ")").addClass("active");
    $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + number + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
    $("#dp-slider .dp_item").removeClass('test');
    $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + number + "]").addClass("test");
    $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
        $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
    });

    $(".text .div").removeClass('is-active');
    $(".div-" + number).addClass('is-active');

    $(".dp_item .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
    $(".dp_item .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');

    $(".item-" + number + " .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
    $(".item-" + number + " .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
}

var myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);

function myTimer() {
    num++;
    if (num > $("#dp-dots li").length) {
        num = 1;
    }
    generalClick(num);
}

$("#home .div, #home .dp_item, #dp-dots").on("mouseenter", function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a clicked element and check if it has .active class.
And just put conditional.

```
$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function () {
   var class = $(this).attr("class");
   if(!class.includes('active')){
   var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
   num = get_slide;
   generalClick(get_slide);
   }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the item in front has class `active` ?

If that's the case and you can work with the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/1) selector:

```
$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item:not(.active)").click(function () {
    var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
    num = get_slide;
    generalClick(get_slide);
});
```

An alternative would to check if the clicked element has class `active`:

```
$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function () {
   var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
   num = get_slide;

   if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
   {
      generalClick(get_slide);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved guys, I added on the element that becomes active the property 'opacity: 1 !important', to eliminate the animation hide ().